# An Error while trying to call a fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I develop a `navigation drawer activity` , but when I m trying to click in a `fragment` it gives me an error and it stopped I'm confused , please could someone help me to figure out the problem, here is the error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nextinnovation.pt.barcodescanner.activity.NavigationDrawerActivity@a5712f1 must implement retryConnectionListener
>           at com.nextinnovation.pt.barcodescanner.fragment.BarcodeFragment.onAttach(BarcodeFragment.java:66)

**BarcodeFragment**

```
public class BarcodeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG= "BarcodeFragment";
private Button btnScan ;
private ScanRequest scanRequest ;

public BarcodeFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode_scanner, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnScan = view.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadAdd(view);

}

private void loadAdd(View view) {
    AdView mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        scanRequest = (ScanRequest) context;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement retryConnectionListener");
    }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnScan :
            // Pass the click event to activity to start the scanner .
            scanRequest.scanBarcode();
            break ;
    }
}


public interface  ScanRequest{
    void scanBarcode();
 }

}
```

**NavigationDrawer**

```
 public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new BarcodeFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new BarcodeFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_search:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SearchFragment()).commit();
            break;
            /*
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        */
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: That Exception message says the issue is in `NavigationDrawerActivity`, not `MainActivity`.

Comment: I'm sorry I edited it @MikeM.

Comment: Well, look at that class declaration. It needs to implement `BarcodeFragment.ScanRequest`, too, if you really mean to use `BarcodeFragment` there, as well.

Comment: @MikeM. thaaaaank you soo soo much